# Calculating 95 Percentile without ControlShiftEnter (CSE, Array formulas) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, percentile, excel-indirect

I have a set of data like this

[image]

Which I am exporting from a tool. This tool can output excel formulas, however this means CSE formulas are not an option. Similarly, the tool has no options for percentile calculations

I need to calculate Percentile (by org unit) of the people counts. This must be a real number. Using array formulas this looks like this:

```
{=LARGE(IF(D10:D27="MyOrg",F10:F27),(ROUND((COUNTIF(D10:D27, (INDIRECT("RC[-5]",0))))-(J3*COUNTIF(D10:D27, (INDIRECT("RC[-5]",0)))),0)+1))}
```

[image]

This is producing the correct result, though without the {}, it gets the large of the entire set.

As I understand it, Index can be used to mimic CSE functions (I had a look at this https://excelxor.com/2014/09/01/index-an-alternative-to-array-cse-formulas/ ) but I am struggling to see exactly how to (or if I even can) apply that here to solve this problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide. Happy to provide the faux sheet I am using to work off of.

Edits:

Cell J3 is [image]

`INDIRECT("RC[-5]",0)` returns MyOrg (in the working Large formula)

Position formula is `=ROUND((COUNTIF(D10:D27, (INDIRECT("RC[-4]",0))))-(J3*COUNTIF(D10:D27, (INDIRECT("RC[-4]",0)))),0)+1`

It was a stepping stone to properly get the large formula to produce the correct. We need to add 1 as Large ranks from 1 to N+1 not 0 to N

Comment: `J3` = percentile (`0.95`)
`INDIRECT("RC[-4]",0)` should be `INDIRECT("RC[-5]",0)`, though weirdly both seem to work? `-5` returns MyOrg. `-4` returns RC[-10]

Position formula = `=ROUND((COUNTIF(D10:D27, (INDIRECT("RC[-4]",0))))-(J3*COUNTIF(D10:D27, (INDIRECT("RC[-4]",0)))),0)+1`

Will update question.

Comment: It's a bit hard to come up with workarounds when we don't know what you're able to work with. Why can't you use array formulas? Can you use array functions that don't require you to press CSE? Can you use working columns?

Comment: My limitations:
- I can only edit values inside of the cells (i.e. formulas), they must start with a =. How do I use an array function without CSE? And what is a working column?. I can't use array formulas (i.e. {=FORMULA}) as outputting that from this tool is translated just as a string, not a formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two examples of non CSE-entered formulas:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,3,(A2:A19="MyOrg")*C2:C19,1)
```

Change the 1 for nth largest value.